# How to align three items, two on the sides and one on the center in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Obviously, if two items only, `MainAxisAlignment.space Between` would be enough, but I have three items, so I have tried with `Align`:

```
             Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Text('Left',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 8.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),),
                     ),
                Align(
                  alignment:Alignment.center,
                  child: Text('Center',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 9.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                      ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Text('Right',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 9.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

But contents are still aligned to center in general, I also tried using `Spacer()` before and after the centered element, the result was much like `spaceEvenly` but with spaces in between.

What I want is the centered element to be fixed in the center no matter what other elements contentes, the left element to be fixed on the left, the right element on the right.

**EDIT**

`space Between` is not working for sure, see [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics):

> MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween:
> Divides the extra space evenly between children.

This does not garantie that the centered element go to center.

Comment: you dont have to add Align widget because  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween code is already doing that

Comment: No, space between did not work, because it depends on the content of every child, if there is a space it would be put in between. that does not garanties an element go to center. Try to put long text to the first element for example.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Yunus Emre Çelik said, you dont need to add Align, spaceBetween is already doing that. But, if your problem still persists, maybe you have a `Column` as parent of your `Row` that need `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,`. Or if you dont, check if your `Row` can expand all width space available.

Anyway you can set your Row like that:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(...),
    Expanded(...),
    Expanded(...),
  ])
```

This force to set equals space to each child

But if you dont want to set equals space for all, can do that:

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // <- center items
            children: [
              Flexible( // <-- flexible space
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text('left left left left left left left left left left left '),
                ),
              ),
              Container( // <-- center
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('center'),
              ),
              Flexible( // <-- flexible space
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text('right'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it does, but can we achieve that without forcing equals space?

Comment: yes! i just updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, remove Align Widget refer Flutter Layout [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Text(
      'Left',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 8.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'Center',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    Text(
      'Right',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 9.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Result-> [image]

#### Answer Updated:

Wrap your Text widget inside [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) Widget

```
Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            'Leftvsdvjwhgehdxuguhe duyxegfygwedue dw',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 8.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            'Center',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            'Right',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 9.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Result Image-> [image]

Comment: Thank you, but please try to put long text in the first element!

Comment: @TyebBellal I have update my answer check it

Comment: Yes, the updates answer gives equal space to each child, but I am not sure that is what I want, although I will vote it, I want the centered element to be in the center, the other element on the extremes without reserving any particular space to each one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, to get rid of the equal space caused by `Expanded`, I removed `Expanded` from the centered element, then set the `fit` properly to `loose` for the left and right elements.

To align sides, I surrounded the left and right elements with 'Row', to set 'MainAxisAlignment' to `start` and `end` respectively, now it works:

```
            Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                fit: FlexFit.loose,//Added this
                child: Row(
                //Surround the Left element with Row aligned to start
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                            Text(
                              'Left',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 8.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                           ]),
              ),
             //No expanded needed to the centered child
             Text( 'Center',style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 9.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),),

              Expanded(
                fit: FlexFit.loose,//Added this too
                child: Row( //Surround the right element with Row aligned to end
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                              'Right',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 9.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                           ),
                           ]),
              ),
            ],
          )
```